# Solving transcendental equation with the unknown on both sides

Tags: transcendental-equations

I need to find the point of intersection between a line segment and a sine wave.

Line: $y=-2x+1$
Wave: $y=\sin x$

I put both equations together.
$-2x+1=\sin x$

I attempt to isolate $x$.
$\sin x+2x=1$

Now I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: draw a careful picture. Unless the intersection is at an obvious point such as $(0,0),$ which does not happen here, the likelihood is that $x$ is unpleasant and can not be solved for in symbols, only numerically approximated.

Comment: There is likely no closed-form solution, but you can show with some elementary calculus that exactly one solution exists, and you can use numerical methods to show that its expansion begins $x = 0.33541\ldots$.

Comment: Search “Kepler equation” on the site for exact solutions